# SubQueries in Laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Can anyone teach me how can we use a query like this in Laravel 4.2

```
SELECT 
    t.Truck_Number, 
    t.Created_dt,
    t.Latitude,
    t.Longitude,
    t.Speed,
    t.Heading 
FROM 
    truckgps t 
INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            Truck_Number,
            max(Created_dt) as MaxDate 
        FROM
            truckgps 
        GROUP BY
            Truck_Number
    ) tm 
ON
    t.Truck_Number = tm.Truck_Number AND
    t.Created_dt = tm.MaxDate
```

this query is provided by someone else, can it be made better using laravel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Laravel Query builder - you can make like this :

```
   $results = DB::select("SELECT 
                         t.Truck_Number, 
                         t.Created_dt, 
                         t.Latitude, 
                         t.Longitude, 
                         t.Speed,
                         t.Heading FROM truckgps t 
        INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT Truck_Number, max(Created_dt) as MaxDate from truckgps group by Truck_Number )   
           tm on t.Truck_Number = tm.Truck_Number and t.Created_dt = tm.MaxDate");
```

or if you have parameters, than you can binding like this :

```
DB::select("select count(1) count from table t where t.id= ? and t.roles_id = ?", 
            array($id, $role_id)
          );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have two tables...I have one solution for your question.. you dont need use joins for this. Table1 name 'truckgps' and table 2 name 'truckgpss' My Ans

```
$truckgps = DB::table('truckgps')->select('Truck_Number','Created','Latitude','Longitude','Speed','Heading ')->get();

foreach ($truckgps as $t)
{

$result = DB::table('truckgpss')->select('MAX(Created_dt) AS MaxDate ','Truck_Number')->where('MaxDate','=',$t->Created_dt )->where('Truck_Number','=',$t->Truck_Number)->groupBy('Truck_Number')
                 ->get();


// if u need value convert array to string use another foreach loop here

foreach ($result as $value)
{

echo $value->Truck_Number; // now u can see the  result truck no..


   }


}
```

I think its help to u...Thank you ..